# NumberFormatException on StringUtils.isBlank method

Tags: java, numberformatexception, apache-stringutils

I am getting a NumberFormatException although I have `StringUtils.isBlank()` and I also added a check for a non-breakable white space character, as mentioned in below code:

```
if (isBlank(amtBeforeTax) || amtBeforeTax.matches("^[\\p{Z}]*$")) {
                ra.setAmtBeforeTax(BigDecimal.ZERO);
            } else {
                ra.setAmtBeforeTax(new BigDecimal(amtBeforeTax));
            }
```

Still I am getting a number format exception on the on the above piece of code. I do not have the control over the `amtBeforeTax`, It's a stream of  data I am getting and just setting it to some other object. I wanted to know what exactly the precussion i will take over here to avoid the exception.

Comment: `StringUtils.isBlank()` doesn't throw `NumberFormatException`

Comment: this is not about StringUtils.isBlank() throwing number format exceptions.  why the isBlank() not able to trace or the the regex for non breakable white Spaces. How to handle non breakable white spaces.

Comment: I think the problem you might be facing is that you need to trim ```amtBeforeTax``` first before you create ```new BigDecimal(amtBeforeTax.trim())```. But just a guess. Anyways Karol Dowbecki anwser is much easier than this so use that. As a side note, there is a dedicated ```NumberUtils.isNumber()``` method which would also help

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve it is to catch the `NumberFormatException`, effectively using `BigDecimal` constructor to perform the validation instead of writing the rules yourself:

```
try {
  ra.setAmtBeforeTax(new BigDecimal(amtBeforeTax))
} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
  ra.setAmtBeforeTax(BigDecimal.ZERO);
}
```

Comment: Thank you..This can be done, But I wanna know why the isBlank() not able to trace or the the regex for non breakable white Spaces. How to handle non breakable white spaces.